# PHP Combining Array within array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing an API and to send data to the application I need some arrays formatted in a certain way I can't seem to get right.

The message exists out of two arrays: Order and Items.  Order is a single array, Items seems to be an array inside an array which goes wrong when multiple items are ordered.

Required format:

```
    {
  "order": {
    "email": "string",
    "phone": "string",
    "company": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    ...
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "description": "string",
      "orderLineId": 0,
      "priceType": "string",
      "productCode": "string",
      "productDescription": "string",
      "quantity": 0,
      "unitPrice": 0
    }
    {
      "description": "string",
      "orderLineId": 0,
      "priceType": "string",
      "productCode": "string",
      "productDescription": "string",
      "quantity": 0,
      "unitPrice": 0
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Output I get:

```
{
  "order": {
    "email": "string",
    "phone": "string",
    "company": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    ...
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "description": "string",
      "orderLineId": 0,
      "priceType": "string",
      "productCode": "string",
      "productDescription": "string",
      "quantity": 0,
      "unitPrice": 0
    }
],
“0”: {
      "items": [
        {
          "description": "string",
          "orderLineId": 0,
          "priceType": "string",
          "productCode": "string",
          "productDescription": "string",
          "quantity": 0,
          "unitPrice": 0
        }
      ]
    }
...
}
```

Code used:

```
$client = array (
                    "order"=>array(
                        "email" => $order->get_billing_email(),
                        "phone" => $order->get_billing_phone(),
                        "company" => $order->get_billing_company(),
                        "firstName" => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
                    )
             );

       foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ){
             $product = $item->get_product();
                           if(is_null($allitems)){
                                  $allitems = array (
                                        "items"=>array([
                                               "description" => $item->get_name(),
                                               "orderLineId"=>0,
                                               "priceType"=>"string",
                                               "productCode"=>$product->get_sku(),
                                               "productDescription" =>"string",
                                               "quantity" => $item->get_quantity(),
                                               "unitPrice"=> $product->get_price()
                                        ])
                                  );
                           }

                    else {
                           $singleitem = array (
                                  "items"=>array([
                                         "description" => $item->get_name(),
                                         "orderLineId"=>0,
                                         "priceType"=>"string",
                                         "productCode"=>$product->get_sku(),
                                         "productDescription" =>"string",
                                         "quantity" => $item->get_quantity(),
                                         "unitPrice"=> $product->get_price()
                                  ])
                           );
                           array_push($allitems, $singleitem);
                    }
             }

       # Combine client and items into one message
             $message = array_merge($client, $allitems);
```

I tried different methots of array_merge, array_push etc but somehow I cant get the items part the way it needs to be.  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mre] including usable sample input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks a bit messy and overcomplicated for a simple loop. It looks like you're re-declaring the items value instead of adding to an items array. I think this should be closer to what you're after:

```php
$order_details = [
    "email" => $order->get_billing_email(),
    "phone" => $order->get_billing_phone(),
    "company" => $order->get_billing_company(),
    "firstName" => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
];

$all_items = [];
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ){
    $this_product = $item->get_product();
    $all_items[] = [
        "description" => $item->get_name(),
        "orderLineId"=>0,
        "priceType"=>"string",
        "productCode"=>$this_product->get_sku(),
        "productDescription" =>"string",
        "quantity" => $item->get_quantity(),
        "unitPrice"=> $this_product->get_price()
    ];
}

$message = [
    "order" => $order_details,
    "items" => $all_items,
];
```